# Continue with a method after completing producer-consumer

Tags: c#, task

I have a producer-consumer application in WPF. After I click a button.

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
        // set up data
        var producer = Producer();
        var consumer = Consumer();
        await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
        // need log the results in Summary method 
        Summary();
     }
}
```

The summary method is a void one; I assume it is proper.

```
private void Summary(){}
async Task Producer(){ await something }
async Task Consumer(){ await something }
```

***EDIT:***

My question is in `Summary()` method I have to use the calculated values from the tasks, however the `Consumer` task is a long running process. The program run `Summary` quickly even not getting the updated values. It use the initial values.

My thought:

```
await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
Summary();
```

**EDIT2: 11:08 AM 11/05/2014**

```
private void Summary()
{
     myFail = 100 - mySuccess;
     _dataContext.MyFail = myFail; // update window upon property changed

 async Task Consumer()
 {
     try
     {
         Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
         {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
                CancellationToken = cToken
         };
         var c = new ActionBlock<T>(
          t=>
         {
              if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                  return;
               dict = Do(t, cToken);
               if(dict["Success"] == "Success")
                   mySuccess++;
```

The current problem is `mySuccess` is always the initial value in `Summary` method.

Comment: I don't understand the question... You want to call the `Summary` method after both tasks are done?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Add Summary"*. Your question is vague.

Comment: Does that code work? If not, what did you expect, what did you observe, any thoughts about the difference? That is *precisely* how you call a method at that point, when those two other tasks has completed. What more do you want?

Comment: Do `Producer` and `Consumer` return a value? or do they update a class level property / field?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Unless you're creating a new `Task` inside your `Consumer`, it should asynchronously wait until both tasks are complete.

Comment: How long it takes to complete is orthogonal to your question. You ask how to "add Summary()" [sic] *after* finishing Producer and Consumer. Can you take one step back, understand that we don't understand one bit about your question and explain it better?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, see my new updated.

Comment: And that should call the `Summary` method only after both has completed. Is that not what is happening? Have you tried debugging, adding a breakpoint to the call to Summary and verifying that it is running too early? Also, this is *copied* code from your program, right? Just so that we don't suddenly discover that you forgot to use `await Task.WhenAll` and only had `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: If your consumer has results to be displayed then it should return those results as the result of the task it returns, rather than returning a non-generic `Task`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the tasks returning from those two methods that are done too soon?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes. I am sure. I have to move the summary into the bottom in `Consumer`. But it maybe a bad design. BTW, it is a TPL dataflow, each run return different results.

Comment: @Servy, I had the second update. Please see it.

Comment: All, just reedited the question to avoid the vague question. Hopefully you can remove the down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) method to execute `Summary` after both producer and consumer have finished:

```
Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer)
    .ContinueWith(continuation => Summary());
```

**EDIT 1**

It seems that you are abusing or using wrong the Producer/Consumer pattern.

The producer is supposed to produce the values and shovel them into one end of a communication pipe. On the other end of the pipe, the consumer consumes the values as they become available. In other words, the consumer **waits** for the producer to produce some value and to put the value in the pipe and for the value to arrive at the end of the pipe.

Usually this involves some sort of signaling mechanism where the producer signals (awakes) the consumer whenever a value has been created.

In your case, you don't have the signaling mechanism and I strongly suspect that your producer is generating only one value. If the later is the case you can just return a value from the "producer".

If however, your producer is creating more than one values, you can use the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) class to send values from producer to consumer.

In your `Producer` class, get a reference to the pipe and put data into it:

```
public class Producer
{
    private BlockingCollection<Data> _pipe;

    public void Start()
    {
        while(!done)
        {
            var value = ProduceValue();
            _pipe.Add(value);
        }
        // Signal the consumer that we're finished
        _pipe.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

In the `Consumer` class wait for the values to arrive and process each one:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private BlockingCollection<Data> _pipe;

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach(var value in _pipe.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // GetConsumingEnumerable will block until a value arrives and 
            // will exit when producer calls CompleteAdding()
            Process(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Having the above in place you can use `ContinueWith` or `await` on the `WhenAll` method to run the `Summary`.

**EDIT 2**

As promised in the comments I have analyzed the code you've posted on [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d69eed8-ddfd-4fe2-9cbb-e0f5790d27fd/generate-a-report-based-on-updated-values-from-task-however-it-used-the-initial-value?forum=csharpgeneral). There are several problems in the code.

First of all and the simplest one to fix is that you're not incrementing the counter in a thread-safe manner. An increment (`value++`) is not an atomic operation so you should be careful when incrementing shared fields. An easy way to do this is:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref evenNumber);
```

Now, the actual problems in your code:

1. As I mentioned earlier, the consumer does not know when the producer has finished producing the values. So, after the producer exits the `for` block it should signal that it has finished. The consumer waits for the finish signal of the producer; otherwise it will wait forever for the next value but there won't be one.
2. You are linking the `BufferBlock` with the consumer code which starts to execute but you're not waiting for the consumer block to finish - you're only waiting 0.5 of a second and exit the consumer method leaving the worker threads of the consumer block to do their work in vain.
3. As a consequence of the above, your `Report` method executes before the processing is finished outputting the value of the `evenNumber` counter at the moment when the method executes not when all processing is finished.

Below is the edited code with some comments:

```
class Program
{
    public static BufferBlock<int> m_Queue = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1000 });
    private static int evenNumber;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var producer = Producer();
        var consumer = Consumer();

        Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer).Wait();
        Report();
    }

    static void Report()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} even numbers", evenNumber);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task Producer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            // Send a value to the consumer and wait for the value to be processed
            await m_Queue.SendAsync(i);
        }
        // Signal the consumer that there will be no more values
        m_Queue.Complete();
    }

    static async Task Consumer()
    {
        var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
        };
        var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(x =>
        {
            int j = DoWork(x);
            if (j % 2 == 0) 
                // Increment the counter in a thread-safe way
                Interlocked.Increment(ref evenNumber);
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        // Link the buffer to the consumer
        using (m_Queue.LinkTo(consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
        {
            // Wait for the consumer to finish.
            // This method will exit after all the data from the buffer was processed.
            await consumerBlock.Completion;
        }
    }

    static int DoWork(int x)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be similar to the code he already has, that is using `await`. The question isn't clear.

Comment: using `ContinueWith` is equivalent to what he's doing now. It wont help, he has another issue with a task prematurely completing.

Comment: Yes, it won't help. I defined some static variables. They have initial values, after tasks done, the values are updated then I want to use the new values to output on the window. Now the question is it use the initial values. I think maybe using `delegate`?

Comment: @RePierre, `Producer` is not a problem. It is in the `Consumer` part.Say `async Task Consumer()
        {
            try
            {
                var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
                    CancellationToken = cToken
                };
                var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(
r=>
{
    if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;
       Dictionary<string, string> d = Do(r, cToken);`, it returns the dictionary, I want to summary by it in the method.

Comment: @HuiZhao, I still don't see how the consumer waits for the producer to start producing the items. Your consumer task finishes before the consumer finishes (maybe even after the producer is started) so the work done by the producer is ignored.

Comment: @RePierre, if you want, would you please go to [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d69eed8-ddfd-4fe2-9cbb-e0f5790d27fd/generate-a-report-based-on-updated-values-from-task-however-it-used-the-initial-value?forum=csharpgeneral). I create a console demo.

Comment: @HuiZhao, I saw the sample. There are at least 2 big problems: 1. Your application finishes before the producer/consumer finishes and 2. There is no way the producer signals to the consumer that it finished adding. I will try to make it work and add another edit to the answer.

Comment: @RePierre, thanks for your effort. I can add `m_Queue.Complete();`, but there are two questions remaining. Originally I had `await consumerBlock.Completion;`, but in my real WPF application. I passed a cacellationtoken to cancel the running task then I got an exception "Additional information: A task was canceled." at that line. The second thing is actually I returned a dictionary in application, evenNumber is just a demo. How can I use `**Interlocked**`?

Comment: @HuiZhao, cancelling a task can be done by throwing an `OperationCanceledException` so this is why you're getting the exception. As for the synchronization, see this article http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @RePierre, I have `catch (OperationCanceledException ex)` in the code. But the question is that it always stop at `await consumerBlock.Completion;`. I have to press F5 then it goes to catch part.

Comment: This is due to the fact that cancellation exception is marshalled back to the calling thread.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of it? I want log the exception in the `catch` block then leave it.

Comment: @RePierre, I marked your answer however I could not up vote it as I don't have enough scores. Sorry about it.(I got two down votes, it is unfair and sadly)